# Summarizing Count of Value

Tags: sql, powerbi, dax

I have a dataset of phone calls that contains a name column. There are repeat names as people can call multiple times. Doing a Count on the column gives us:

- Person A - 3 Calls
- Person B - 5 Calls
- Person C - 2 Calls
- Person D - 3 Calls

What I really want is the breakdown of # of calls, which I'll use as my graph axis:

- 2 Calls - 1
- 3 Calls - 2
- 4 Calls - 0
- 5 Calls - 1

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1):

If you want a SQL solution, this is basically aggregation:

```
select numcalls, count(*)
from t
group by numcalls
order by numcalls;
```

This will not fill in the 0 values.  For that, you can use a table constructor and `left join`:

```
select v.numcalls, count(t.numcalls);
from (values (2), (3), (4), (5)) v(numcalls) left join
     t
     on v.numcalls = t.numcalls
group by v.numcalls
order by v.numcalls;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do not need 0 values of number of calls, you can work with a subselect in SQL

```
select numbercalls, count(*)
from (
  select person, count(*) as numbercalls
  from t
  group by person
) group by numbercalls
order by numbercalls;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in DAX along these lines:

```
CalculatedTable =
VAR Summary = SUMMARIZE(Table1, Table1[Person], "Cnt", COUNT(Table1[Call]))
VAR NumCalls = SELECTCOLUMNS(GENERATESERIES(2,5), "Calls", [Value])
RETURN ADDCOLUMNS(NumCalls, "People", SUMX(Summary, IF([Cnt] = [Calls], 1, 0)))
```

First, you summarize your data to get a count for each person.

Then you create a table, `NumCalls` with a single column, `Calls`, which has values from `2` to `5`.

Finally, you add a column to that table which counts the number of people whose `Cnt` in the `Summary` table matches the number of `Calls` in the current table.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this for counting, check if count is null, and then GROUP BY and ORDER BY :

```
SELECT numcalls, ISNULL(count(*),0)
FROM t
GROUP BY numcalls
ORDER BY numcalls;
```

Comment: do you need ISNULL on count(*)